# Список списков python

Tags: python

У меня есть список списков выглядит так ---

```
data=[['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],  ['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],  ['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru']]
```

Мне нужно сделать и сохранить вот так---тоесть удалить внешний список

```
data=['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],
['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],
['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru']
```

с помощью кода получается это реализовать вот так

```
i = 0 
while i < len(data): 
    print(data[i]) 
    i += 1
```

Но список data не изменился.

Comment: Так как хочешь сохранить, сохранить нельзя. Ты хочешь в оду переменную засунуть 3 значения
[[данные], [данные], [данные]] -- это список, внутри которого вложенные списки

Comment: То, что вы там написали - это на самом деле кортеж, смысла в этом особого нет. Если вы `data` после этого напечатаете, там всё-равно будут скобки снаружи, просто не квадратные, а круглые.

Comment: Просто я не могу сохранить список внутри списков в sqllite бд, чтоб сохранить это, нужен просто список

Answer (score 2):

По сути вы пытаетесь преобразовать список в кортеж, это можно сделать так:

```
data = [['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],  ['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru'],  ['gov', 'Последние новости - Россельхознадзор', 'https://fsvps.gov.ru']]
d = tuple(data)
print(d)
```